# select2.js and select with content of two columns visible - laravel

Tags: jquery, forms, laravel, laravel-5, jquery-select2

I have a form and a select field in it. I also use select2.js to style the field

The select is populated by this collection

```
$dis = array(null => 'Please select district name...') + District::orderBy('id','asc')->lists('name_region', 'id')->all();
```

The code in my view is

```
{!! Form::select('electoraldistrict_id', $dis, Input::old('electoraldistrict_id')) !!}
```

Problem: 
Now in the select field I only see the `name` of the district.

How I can make the form to display BOTH `id` and `name` - so that in the field I would see sht like this:

```
1 - first district
2 - second district
```

instead of

```
first district
second district
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify the database results to do that:

```
$modifiedDistricts = array_map(function($district) {
    return [
        'id' => $district['id'],
        'name_region' => "{$district['id']} - {$district['name_region']}",
    ];
}, $dis);
```

Comment: I just ran on an issue. The code gives error "array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given"

Comment: The order is wrong in your `array_map`, as it should be `array_map($func, $dis)`;

Comment: I am confused. How the code you provided sould be modified?